# Predicate Logic - Translate the following statement into the notation of predicate

Tags: logic, logic-translation

Question: Translate the following statement into the notation of predicate
logic. 

P: Not all natural numbers are even. 

 My solution: 

P: ~[∀x ∈ N, x/2 ∉ Z] 

 P: ∃x ∈ N, x/2 ∈ Z

 Is my solution correct as my answer seems to be completely different to what is says in the worksheet.

Comment: NO; the second one reads: "there is a natural number that is divisible by two (i.e. *even*)".

Comment: Why $\mathbb Z$ ? If $x$ is a natural, its half (if it exists) is also a natural.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

You could express it this way:

$$\sim[\forall n \in \Bbb{N}, \exists m \in \Bbb{N}, 2m = n]$$

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the division, which is not an internal operation in
the integers. Hence I would write :
$$
\exists x\in\mathbb{N},\forall y\in\mathbb{N}\quad x\not=2y.
$$

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot use division. If x/2 returns an integer does that not show that x is even?

Comment: In standard predicate logic, all functions are treated as total -- since partial functions create truth-value gaps, and standard predicate logic is two valued.